# Python - Setting an attribute to the value of a method - cleanest way?

Tags: python, django

I want a nice convenient attribute to do the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user = User.objects.get(id=2)
user.company
<Company: Big Company L.L.C>
```

I am currently solving this using lambda.  In searching for an answer it looks like perhaps the "right" way to solve this would be to use `types.MethodType` but I can't seem to get my head around it.  Yes, I have read [Raymond excellent guide](http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm) but I'm clearly missing something..  Here is my current solution for those who are interested..

```
# Defined Elsewhere
class User:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
class Company(models.Model):
    users =  models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="companies", blank=True, null=True)

# Here is the meat of this..
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    """This defines Users"""
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    def get_company(self):
        try:
            companies = self.user.companies.all()[0]
        except (AttributeError, IndexError):
            return None

User.company = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0].get_company())
```

Right now this works..  **But is there a better way - I'm not crazy about lambdas??**

Comment: Is the lambda causing any problems? If not, you have a working implementation of what you're trying to do – why make things difficult?

Comment: No it's working but I'm not entirely comfortable with them.  I've always looked at them with the anti-pattern eye...

Comment: Be careful with `except AttributeError, IndexError:` in Python 2.x.  It will only catch `AttributeError`, and assign the caught exception to `IndexError`.  Use `except (AttributeError, IndexError):` instead.

Comment: Yeah - good catch I fixed it in my code!

Comment: @rh0dium: I tried searching around for idiomatic monkeypatching, and  found a 2008 mailing list posting by GvR with some code that was just assigning a regular function to a class. Obviously that's not authoritative, but it's a data point in support of just keeping it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand correctly what your goal is, but from what I think I understand, it doesn't seem necessary to do any crazy stuff with descriptors here, let alone `types.MethodType`.  A simple property is fine, and if you don't like the lambda, you can use an ordinary function decorated with `@property`:

```
class User:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    @property
    def company(self):
        return UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=self)[0].get_company())
```

**Edit:** If you can't touch the `User` class, you can create a derived class adding the desired property:

```
class MyUser(User):
    @property
    def company(self):
        return UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=self)[0].get_company())
```

Comment: You can't really add methods to a class in a Django library.

Comment: @Inerdia: `User` doesn't seem to be a class in a Django library.  (And if you can't change a certain class, simply derive from it instead of monkey-patching it).

Comment: The OP seems to refer to the Django [Auth module] (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User). Subclassing won't really help because the module's functions won't return your subclass.

Comment: @Inerdia: I see.  In this case, monkey-patching is the only option.

Answer (score -1):

Building on @SvenMarnach's answer, you can still accomplish the same thing without using lambda. Though you still have to monkey-patch:

```
def _get_user_company(user):
    return UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)[0].get_company()
User.company = property(_get_user_company)
```

Comment: Umm.. I thought get_or_create returns a tuple..??... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I normally use something like `obj, created = MyModel.objects.get_or_create()`, so the array selector conjures `filter` to my mind.